# How to create a table using user input with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'm trying to create a table using a user input prompt which is saved into a variable. I want to be able to take that variable and make it an even number of rows and columns. So for example if the user input is 5, I want to make a 5x5 table.

I'm able to take the user's input and make the correct amount of rows, but I'm having trouble with the columns.

Could anyone offer some insight on my code? My js fiddle is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //cache all jquery objects in variables
    var $button = $('.button');
    var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
    var $bones = $('.bones');
    var $rows = $('.rows');

    $button.click(function() {

        //prompt user for input on table size
        var inp = prompt("Enter a number");

        for (var i = 0; i < inp; i++) {
            $bones.append("<tr class='rows'></tr>");
            $rows.append("<td class='block'></td>");
        };
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/81zv9zjs/

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the td element within the tr elements, so instead of a single loop like the one you have, try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inp; i++) {

  var elem = $("<tr class='rows'></tr>");

  for (var j = 0; j < inp; j++) {
    elem.append("<td class='block'></td>");
  }

  $bones.append(elem);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //cache all jquery objects in variables
  var $button = $('.button');
  var $bones = $('.bones');

  $button.click(function() {
    //prompt user for input on table size
    var rr = prompt("Rows");
    var cc = prompt("Cols");

    for (var i = 0; i < rr; i++) {
      var row = $('<tr class="rows"></tr>');
      for (var j = 0; j < cc; j++) {
        row.append('<td width="20">&nbsp;</td>');
      }
      $bones.append(row);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
table {width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;}
th,td {border: 2px solid #ccc;}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  background-color: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button"> Click Here! </a>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <table class="bones"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: what is difference from the previous ans?

Comment: Ha! Looks like Ben copied my answer exactly -- *and* he managed to do it 20 minutes before I even posted mine. *Shows what happens when you walk away from the computer in the middle of answering a question...* **Ben should be awarded the accepted answer,** but I'll leave mine here only because it has a demo. +1 to Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a wider approach. Assuming that you have to create a table with some data in it. That data has to be provided in an object structure in a similar fashion to the following;

```
[ { Prop_0: 'Value_0',
    Prop_1: 'Value_1',
    Prop_2: 'Value_2',
    Prop_3: 'Value_3',
    Prop_4: 'Value_4' },
  { Prop_0: 'Value_5',
    Prop_1: 'Value_6',
    Prop_2: 'Value_7',
    Prop_3: 'Value_8',
    Prop_4: 'Value_9' },
  { Prop_0: 'Value_10',
    Prop_1: 'Value_11',
    Prop_2: 'Value_12',
    Prop_3: 'Value_13',
    Prop_4: 'Value_14' },
  { Prop_0: 'Value_15',
    Prop_1: 'Value_16',
    Prop_2: 'Value_17',
    Prop_3: 'Value_18',
    Prop_4: 'Value_19' },
  { Prop_0: 'Value_20',
    Prop_1: 'Value_21',
    Prop_2: 'Value_22',
    Prop_3: 'Value_23',
    Prop_4: 'Value_24' } ]
```

In which the properties will designate the headers and the values are the `<td>` cell values. `tableMaker` will take this object as first argument and turn it into a table HTML mark up text. If the second argument is true then the first object's properties will be used for `<th>` data. So lets see...

```js
function tableMaker(o,h) {
  var keys = o.length && Object.keys(o[0]),
  rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                  : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
  rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
  return rows.length ? "<table>" + rows + "</table>" : "";
}

var data = [{"Prop_0":"Value_0","Prop_1":"Value_1","Prop_2":"Value_2","Prop_3":"Value_3","Prop_4":"Value_4"},{"Prop_0":"Value_5","Prop_1":"Value_6","Prop_2":"Value_7","Prop_3":"Value_8","Prop_4":"Value_9"},{"Prop_0":"Value_10","Prop_1":"Value_11","Prop_2":"Value_12","Prop_3":"Value_13","Prop_4":"Value_14"},{"Prop_0":"Value_15","Prop_1":"Value_16","Prop_2":"Value_17","Prop_3":"Value_18","Prop_4":"Value_19"},{"Prop_0":"Value_20","Prop_1":"Value_21","Prop_2":"Value_22","Prop_3":"Value_23","Prop_4":"Value_24"}],
tableHTMLText = tableMaker(data,true);

document.write(tableHTMLText);
console.log(tableHTMLText);
```

I hope it helps.